# Configuraciones específicas para matplotlib embebido en PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, embebido

Tengo esta configuración actual:

```
def config_matplotlib(self):
    self.fig = Figure((130.0, 6.0), dpi=70, facecolor="#F6F4F2")
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
    self.canvas.setParent(self.window.graphicsGroupBox)
    self.window.graphicsGridLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
    self.graph_a = self.fig.add_subplot(311)
    self.graph_b = self.fig.add_subplot(312)
    self.graph_c = self.fig.add_subplot(313)

    self.graph_a.grid(True)
    self.graph_b.grid(True)
    self.graph_c.grid(True)

    self.graph_plot_a = self.graph_a.plot(
                [],
                linewidth=1,
                color=("darkorange"),
                )[0]
    self.graph_plot_b = self.graph_b.plot(
                [],
                linewidth=1,
                color=("darkorange"),
                )[0]
    self.graph_plot_c = self.graph_c.plot(
                [],
                linewidth=1,
                color=("darkorange"),
                )[0]

    ajust = {"top": 0.95,
            "bottom": 0.1,
            "right": 0.97,
            "left": 0.05,
            "wspace": 0.2,
            "hspace": 0.2,}
    self.fig.subplots_adjust(**ajust)

    #graficar (lo que se ve cuando se ejecuta el programa por)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Da como resultado lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener una gráfica con los estilos de línea y los límites iguales a los que tengo aquí:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He revisado documentación y tutoriales y no encuentro cómo poner los estilos de línea, imprimir dos gráficos en un mismo *plot*, y adicionalmente meter texto, todo esto embebido, claro está, por que normalmente sé como se hace.

Quiero tener la configuración inicial con los límites establecidos, y lo otros ponerlo en una función `update_plot()`.

Comment: En principio se hace de la misma forma "embebido" y "normal", empleando los métodos `.plot()` con los estilos de línea y `.text()`. ¿Puedes intentar eso y decirnos qué errores estás obteniendo?

Comment: Prueba a poner el código completo. Según está parece que hay varias cosas mezcladas. `self` parece una instancia de `Figure` y luego vuelves a añadir `self.fig` que oarece que se refiere a otra instancia de `Figure` diferente.

Answer (score 1):

1. Para los límites usa `{tu gráfico}.axes.set_xlim([{desde}, {hasta}])` y `{tu gráfico}.axes.set_ylim([{desde}, {hasta}])` para los limites
2. para colocar líneas discontinuas usa `'--'` en la función plot como parámetro.
3. Para plotear 2 gráficos usa `{tu gráfico}.plot(data1, {argumentos para el primer gráfico}, data2, {argumentos para el segundo gráfico}, ...)`

En la siguiente parte te muestro un ejemplo con tu función( he modificado algunas cosas por que no las encuentro declaradas en tu código)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.config_matplotlib()

    def config_matplotlib(self):
        self.fig = Figure((130.0, 6.0), dpi=70, facecolor="#F6F4F2")

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.graph_a = self.fig.add_subplot(311)
        self.graph_b = self.fig.add_subplot(312)
        self.graph_c = self.fig.add_subplot(313)

        self.graph_a.grid(True)
        self.graph_a.axes.set_xlim([1, 3])
        self.graph_a.axes.set_ylim([0, 120])
        data1 = [10*(x-1)**2 for x in range(1, 5)]
        data2 = [-50 * (x - 4) for x in range(1, 5)]
        self.graph_a.plot(data1, '--', data2, '--')

        self.graph_b.grid(True)
        self.graph_b.axes.set_xlim([1, 3])
        self.graph_b.axes.set_ylim([0, 120])
        self.graph_b.plot(data1, '--')

        self.graph_c.grid(True)
        self.graph_c.axes.set_xlim([1, 3])
        self.graph_c.axes.set_ylim([0, 120])
        self.graph_c.plot(data2, '--')

        self.graph_plot_a = self.graph_a.plot(
            [],
            linewidth=1,
            color=("darkorange"),
        )[0]
        self.graph_plot_b = self.graph_b.plot(
            [],
            linewidth=1,
            color=("darkorange"),
        )[0]
        self.graph_plot_c = self.graph_c.plot(
            [],
            linewidth=1,
            color=("darkorange"),
        )[0]

        ajust = {"top": 0.95,
                 "bottom": 0.1,
                 "right": 0.97,
                 "left": 0.05,
                 "wspace": 0.2,
                 "hspace": 0.2, }
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(**ajust)

        # graficar (lo que se ve cuando se ejecuta el programa por)
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]